# Calculate the average of a row in a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, average

I have this simple method printing a two dimensional array:

```
public static void printtda() {

    int[][] temps = { {27,28,26,29,30}, {26,25,25,37,40} };

    for (int i=0; i<temps.length; i++) {

        for (int g=0; g< temps[i].length; g++) {

            System.out.print(temps[i][g] +"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```

What I'm now looking for is a way to print the average of each row, so the average of **27,28,26,29,30** and **26,25,25,37,40**.

Any reply greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to create method calculating average for one dimensional array? If yes you can apply this method to each row like `for (int[] row : array){double avg = yourAvgMethod(row);}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a sum while looping over each array:

```
public static void printtda() {

  int[][] temps = { {27,28,26,29,30}, {26,25,25,37,40} };

  for (int i=0; i<temps.length; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int g=0; g< temps[i].length; g++) {
        sum+=temps[i][g];
        System.out.print(temps[i][g] +"  ");
    }
    System.out.println(sum/temps[i].length);
    System.out.println();
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java 8 `IntStream`:

```
public static void printtda() {

    int[][] temps = { {27,28,26,29,30}, {26,25,25,37,40} };

    for (int i=0; i<temps.length; i++) {
        for (int g=0; g< temps[i].length; g++) {
            System.out.print(temps[i][g] +"  ");
        }
        double avg = IntStream.of(temps[i]).avarage().getAsDouble();
        System.out.println("The avarage is: " + avg);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

}